# Smart Chinese Analysis Elasticsearch returns unicodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to analyse documents in Elasticsearch using Smart Chinese Analyser, but, instead of getting the analysed Chinese characters, Elasticsearch returns the unicodes of these characters. For example:

```
PUT /test_chinese
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "default": {
                        "type": "smartcn"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}

GET /test_chinese/_analyze?text='我说世界好!'
```

I expect to get every chinese character, but I get:

```
{
    "tokens": [
      {
          "token": "25105",
          "start_offset": 3,
          "end_offset": 8,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 4
      },
      {
          "token": "35828",
          "start_offset": 11,
          "end_offset": 16,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 8
      },
      {
          "token": "19990",
          "start_offset": 19,
          "end_offset": 24,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 12
      },
      {
          "token": "30028",
          "start_offset": 27,
          "end_offset": 32,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 16
      },
      {
          "token": "22909",
          "start_offset": 35,
          "end_offset": 40,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 20
      }
   ]
}
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem regarding my question. It seems that there is a bug in Sense.
Here you can find the conversation with Zachary Tong, Elasticsearch Developer: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/smart-chinese-analysis-returns-unicodes-instead-of-chinese-tokens/37133
Here is the ticket for the bug found: https://github.com/elastic/sense/issues/88